# How can I improve my PSX/PS1 fog?

Tags: shaders, eevee-render-engine, volumetrics

**Blender:** 3.62 
**Art Style:** PS1/PSX 
**Game:** Ecco The Dolphin: Defender Of The Future

---

I'm using the Principled Volume Shader on my World Node to achieve a colored fog effect.
It's ok but i have 2 problems with the look...

1. The fog starts immediately and not 5-10m away from the camera.
2. Increasing density or emission strength drowns out any close by details because it's so intense.

---

[image: My Render]

[image: Game Screenshot]

[image: World Node]

Comment: I would probably do this with a _Mist Pass_ in the _Compositor_. Much quicker to render and you can easily set from which distance of the camera it should start, how far it should reach and adjust it with a _Color Ramp_ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Like [Gordon Brinkmann](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/99859/gordon-brinkmann) said, the mist pass was 100% the way to go over the principled volume shader.

**New Mist Pass**
[image: Composite]

Doesn't quite show the end result here but enjoy the nausea coaster :) 
https://youtu.be/sd-1d8yoC-g